# .LCD35-show changes resolution on HDMI instead of changing screen

Tags: raspbian

so the command `LCD-hdmi` changes resoluution to my monitor correctly but lately I decided go back to LCD35 waveshare by using `LCD35-show` command like under [THIS](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_HDMI_LCD) link and PI says LCD configure 0 right before it reboot, shuts down than stand up using HDMI but with LCD35 resolution.

The resistant touch screen stays white for the duration of both processes.

Any idea what should I dig into?

I have wiped boot/config completly to let the command do the job but nothing changes.